# Frame background colour in ios in xamarin forms not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, frame

Frame background colour is applied through converter for ios and android.
for android it is working fine.But for ios is not working properly.

Please find the below Xaml code.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <ViewCell.View>
                <Frame Margin="0,5"
                       Padding="10"
                       CornerRadius="5"
                       BackgroundColor="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource boolToColor}}">
                  <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           TextColor="White"
                           Style="{StaticResource lblSecondaryStyle}" />
                    <Image Grid.Column="1"
                           Source="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource boolToImage}}"
                           HeightRequest="30"
                           WidthRequest="30"
                           Aspect="AspectFit"
                           HorizontalOptions="End" />
                  </Grid>
                </Frame>
              </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Below is my boolToColorConverter logic.

```
public class BoolToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return value;
            }
            if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(value))
            {
                return (Color)Application.Current.Resources["primary"];
            }
            return (Color)Application.Current.Resources["Secondary_blue_background"];
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Note :- In my Xaml code i have also used boolToImageConverter which is binding to the same property IsSelected and to my surprise it is working as expected.

Please guide me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you please share some of the relevant code, that way we can see what might be causing the problem.

Comment: @ Digitalsa1nt - Please find the code above

Answer (score 0):

You try the below solution, this will surely work for you.

```
<DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <ViewCell.View>
              <Grid>
                <Frame Margin="0,5"
                       Padding="10"
                       CornerRadius="5"
                       IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected}"
                       BackgroundColor="{StaticResource TrueColorHere}">
                  <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           TextColor="White"
                           Style="{StaticResource lblSecondaryStyle}" />
                    <Image Grid.Column="1"
                           Source="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource boolToImage}}"
                           HeightRequest="30"
                           WidthRequest="30"
                           Aspect="AspectFit"
                           HorizontalOptions="End" />
                  </Grid>
                </Frame>

                <Frame Margin="0,5"
                       Padding="10"
                       CornerRadius="5"
                       IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource inverseBool}}"
                       BackgroundColor="{StaticResource FalseColorHere}">
                  <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           TextColor="White"
                           Style="{StaticResource lblSecondaryStyle}" />
                    <Image Grid.Column="1"
                           Source="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource boolToImage}}"
                           HeightRequest="30"
                           WidthRequest="30"
                           Aspect="AspectFit"
                           HorizontalOptions="End" />
                  </Grid>
                </Frame>
              </Grid> 
              </ViewCell.View>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
```

Enjoy Coding :)